# Fit a Fourier Model with zero a0

Tags: matlab, fft, data-fitting

following code finds coefficients in Fourier series

```
load enso;
f = fit(month,pressure,'fourier2');
```

output of the code:

```
 General model Fourier1:
 f(x) =  a0 + a1*cos(x*w) + b1*sin(x*w)
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a0 =       10.63  (10.22, 11.03)
   a1 =       2.876  (2.187, 3.565)
   b1 =       1.177  (0.09191, 2.261)
   w =      0.5263  (0.5225, 0.5301)
```

I need to find coefficients for function f(x) =  a1*cos(x*w) + b1*sin(x*w), so a0 should be either 0 or should not be in the formula at all. How to do this?

Comment: Why do you specifically want the intercept term to be 0? What is your rationale behind that?

Comment: because in the method of synthetic turbulence generation the author uses decomposition without a0

Answer (score 1):

Do you want `'fourier1'` or `'fourier2'`? Because you have both in your question. You can limit `a0` to 0 by using fit options. Below are the fits for both, the `-Inf` to `Inf` are ranges for the `a`'s, `b`'s and `w` while the `0` to `0` is limiting `a0`.

```
load enso;

ft1 = fittype('fourier1');

options1 = fitoptions(ft1);
options1.Lower = [0 -Inf -Inf -Inf];
options1.Upper = [0  Inf  Inf  Inf];

f1 = fit(month,pressure,ft1,options1)

ft2 = fittype('fourier2');

options2 = fitoptions(ft2);
options2.Lower = [0 -Inf -Inf -Inf  -Inf  -Inf];
options2.Upper = [0  Inf  Inf  Inf   Inf   Inf];

f2 = fit(month,pressure,ft2,options2)
```

Edit:

It runs fine for me. That's odd...

```
f1 = 

     General model Fourier1:
     f1(x) =  a0 + a1*cos(x*w) + b1*sin(x*w)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a0 =           0  (fixed at bound)
       a1 =       2.258  (-1.631, 6.148)
       b1 =       2.406  (-1.317, 6.13)
       w =      0.5311  (0.516, 0.5462)
```

Comment: it says that equal lower and upper bounds are not permitted. I need 'fourier1', sorry didn't notice that I used both.

Comment: I did't get that error, can you take off all of the `;`'s and post the results?